# Can an input (type=text) be a jQuery droppable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop

I am trying out jQuery-UI drag-drop feature.
I was able to easily convert a div into a droppable but making a text box a Droppable doesn't work.

```
jQuery('input[type=text]:visible').droppable({
    drop: function (e, ui){
        console.log('dropping',ui); //--> this never gets called
     jQuery(this).val(jQuery(ui.helper).text());
}
});
```

Is it the case that the default browser behavior prevents text fields and text areas from being droppables?

EDIT:
It doesn't work only when the input field is a part of a draggable..

http://jsfiddle.net/guNTP/4/

```
<span>hello world!<input></span>

$("input").droppable({
  drop: function(event, ui) {
    alert(ui.draggable.text());
  }
});

$("span").draggable({helper:function(){
    return jQuery("<span>hello</span>");
}});
```

Comment: so you could move the whole span - with the input - into the input in it -- that cannot work...

if you wrap every word in another tag, e.g. a `<b>`, it works very well. look at the updated example here: http://jsfiddle.net/guNTP/5/

Comment: Your error in reasoning gets clear when you replace the `helper: function() {...}` with `helper:'clone`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it can be: http://jsfiddle.net/guNTP/

Comment: Thanks.. but it looks like the droppable doesn't work if it is a part of the draggable.. I've updated my original question to reflect this.

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#myinput").droppable({
  drop: function(event, ui) {
    $(this).val( $(this).val() + ui.draggable.text());
  }
});

$("span").draggable({revert:true});
```